# Conditional statement: if is_category, append at the end of page

Tags: categories, conditional-content

I'm really new to code, so forgive me if the question seems dull.

I have set up a very simple WP site its only purpose is to collect content from authors to then export some xml file in order to create an Indesign document. Content has the same format throughout (there are some ACF for the authors to upload it in a organised way) and each post has an assigned category.

The site has 29 category in total (which are the London Boroughs) and posts (Buildings name with address and description) are organised alphabetically with `query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=ASC');`in `category.php`.

Now: one category is slightly different. It's called Walk and Tours; here I collect content which is slightly different. Posts with this category will also have one (only one) from the another categories assigned (i.e 'Walks and Tours, 'Westminster').

I'd like to append the content of this category at the end of the post's other assigned category's page (See example below of aimed result).

Category: 'Westminster'
post 1,
post 2,
post 3,
...

Category 'Walks and Tours', 'Westminster)
post x 
post y
post z

I assume there's a need for a simple conditional statement that says "If this post has this category *and* this category too, then append (?).

Hope to find and answer here!
Many thanks,
A

Comment: you might need to append a custom query and loop based on the ids of current category and  the category 'walks and tours', using 'category__and' as parameter; https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( in_category('Walks and Tours') && in_category('Westminster') ) {

//append whatever

}
```

You'd place that where you want the output to occur, within the Loop, of course.